# Using the glom library with Python: Turning a list result into a dictionary with key generated by a Python function

Tags: python-3.x, glom

I'm using the Python library [glom](https://github.com/mahmoud/glom) to extract data from a dictionary that contains lists.

This question is about unterstanding how **glom** works with **user defined functions** and how I can move data **from lists into dictionaries** within glom.

As an example, I'm trying to convert the data into a dictionary directly.

```
# in the real world, this data has way many more fields
data = {'vessels': [{'aisStatic': {'mmsi': 1, 'name': 'name1'}},
               {'aisStatic': {'mmsi': 2, 'name': 'name2'}}],
       'timestamp': None}

# this is the glob spec to extract the data 
spec = ('vessels',[({'mmsi':'aisStatic.mmsi','name':'aisStatic.name'})])

# an example to generate a new key based on data & position
def keyfunc(i, v):
    return f"v{i}-{v['mmsi']}"

result = glom(data, spec)

wanted_result = {keyfunc(i,v): v for i, v in enumerate(result)}
```

The wanted result looks like this

```
{'v0-1': {'mmsi': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, 'v1-2': {'mmsi': 2, 'name': 'name2'}}
```

For the example, I'm using a comprehension outside of **glom** to get the wanted result, since glom returns a list.

I am looking at a way to get the same results directly via a glom spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working solution is to use Invoke on the *enumerate* function.

```
from glom import merge, Invoke

data = {
    "vessels": [
        {"aisStatic": {"mmsi": 1, "name": "name1"}},
        {"aisStatic": {"mmsi": 2, "name": "name2"}},
    ],
    "timestamp": None,
}

spec = (
    "vessels",
    [{"mmsi": "aisStatic.mmsi", "name": "aisStatic.name"}],
    Invoke(enumerate).specs(T),
    [lambda x: {f"v{x[0]}-{x[1].get('mmsi')}": x[1]}],
    merge,
)

print(glom(data, spec))
```

which returns the requested result

```
{'v0-1': {'mmsi': 1, 'name': 'name1'}, 'v1-2': {'mmsi': 2, 'name': 'name2'}}
```